CSV not loading as point layer, in QGIS
I know this is a common issue, but I couldn't find a solution, so I hope someone can help me.
I'm trying to load this CSV as a point layer, but none of the points are loading.


They are not DMS coordinates (degrees, minutes, seconds) but decimal degrees.

what @user30184 means is don't tick the DMS box

As commented by  user30184 and
Ian Turton - Your coordinates are decimal degrees (DD), not degrees, minutes and seconds (DMS).  If you untick the DMS checkbox, your CSV should be added correctly.

QGIS User Manual: Importing a delimited text file
